# How do I enumerate nested JObject using JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a stringified json object which I parse using `JObject.Parse` and get the result below-

```
{{
   "payload": {
       "firstName": "John",
       "lastName": "Doe"
    }
}}
```

This was my input -

```
"{ \r\n\"payload\": {\r\n\t\"firstName\":\"John\", \r\n\t\"lastName\": \"Doe\"\r\n }}"
```

The extra brackets are the start and the end are added by the parser. I want to iterate over this object and display the key value for first name and last name.

```
foreach (var property in jobject)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
}
```

However, I don't know because of the two brackets or because of the nested structure I cannot get to the properties inside. I tried a recursive approach to parse the json but haven't been successful yet. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This is not a valid json.

Comment: How is  not a valid json? JObject.Parse didn't throw any error? If it is about the extra brackets in the start and the end then the parser added it.

Comment: The json in post is not a valid one. I can't parse it with [JObject](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iIEPii) or validate neither with jsonlint.com nor with jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.

Comment: If you copied the whole thing it won't be a valid now. The first and last curly bracket is added by the jObject.parse

Comment: Please add a valid json which you are parsing.

Comment: @ZankhanaRana Brackets are definitely not added by `JObject.Parse`.  Most likely you are looking at the JSON in a debugger and the debugger added the extra braces.  The way to get the "real" JSON is to write it out to the console or to a file.

Comment: I updated the question. @brianarogers yes I am checking in the debugger. And even after logging it to the console I see the extra brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate all nested objects as well you can do something like this:

```
var p = JObject.Parse(...);
foreach (var a in p.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    if (a is JObject obj)
        foreach (var prop in obj.Properties())
            if (!(prop.Value is JObject) && !(prop.Value is JArray))
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value);
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: @ZankhanaRana glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to access to object. If it is not ok please add the part of parsing object to question.

```
yourobj["payload"].ToObject<YourObject>()
```